# How can I start Springsource STS using java.exe from the command line?

Tags: spring-tool-suite

I would like to start SpringSource STS without using STS.exe.
Probably this is possible using "java ..." command line.

What command should I use? And how can I take advantage of STS.ini parameters.

Answer (score 1):

As described here:
https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_run_Eclipse%3F
you can launch Eclipse/STS form the command line via:

java -jar eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.0.0.v20070606.jar

In STS this would mean to go to the directory with the "sts-3.6.4.RELEASE" folder inside and execute something like:

java -jar sts-3.6.4.RELEASE/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar

I don't know how to tell this launcher to re-use the settings from the STS.ini file, but I guess you would at least have to specify the JVM options directly since you are starting up the JVM yourself now.

Hope this helps!